# chess style pattern

Tags: javascript, math, modulo

I'd like to create a pattern like in the picture for `i` rows and `j` columns:

This code does not work for every case.

```
var z = 0
  for(var i = 0;i<s;i++)
    for(var j = 0;j<o;j++,z++)
      color = (z%2==1?"white":"gray");
```

[image: chess]

[You can play with it here.](http://jsbin.com/apusoc/2/)

Comment: Works fine here, has your example been updated?

Comment: yes, the problem is solved, thanks to Deltaflux.

Comment: You should post an answer and accept it so whoever searches for this in the future will find the answer instead of just "the problem is solved".

Comment: @h2ooooooo it is not allowed within 10 mins

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this, adding together i and j rather than using a third variable:

```
for (var i = 0; i < s; i++)
  for (var j = 0; j < o; j++)
    color = ( (i + j) % 2 == 1 ? "white" : "gray" );
```

Answer (score 2):

Use this condition:

```
color = (i + j) % 2 == 1 ? "white" : "gray";
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `x` and `y` and get the modulo.

```
// ...

var table$ = $('<table>');
for(var y = 0; y < s ; y++) {
  var tr$ = $('<tr>');
  for(var x = 0; x < o; x++) {
    var td$ = $('<td>').css({
      width: p_w,
      height: p_h,
      'background-color': getColor(x, y)
    });
    tr$.append(td$);
  }
  table$.append(tr$);
}

// ...
var Color = {
  GRAY: '#aaa',
  WHITE: '#fff'
};

function getColor(x, y) {
  return (x + y) % 2 === 0 ? Color.WHITE: Color.GRAY;
}
```

[**Demo**](http://jsbin.com/apusoc/12/)